# How to check if set_status_header is set to 404 in view in CodeIgniter?

Tags: php, codeigniter

This is how I set header **$this->output->set_status_header('404');** in controller:

```
<?php
class custom404 extends CI_Controller
{
    public function __construct()
    {
            parent::__construct();
    }

    public function index()
    {
        $this->output->set_status_header('404');
        $this->view_data['page_title'] = 'Page not found';
        $this->view_data['main_content'] = 'error404';
        $this->load->view('template', $this->view_data);
    }
}
?>
```

Then I need to somehow check status header 404 in the view?

Any advice beside sending another variable in $this->view_data?

Comment: I'm curious, why do you need to know if 404 is set when you are in a 404 view?  Shouldn't it always be set to 404 when you output that view?

Comment: Yeah, but how to get that value? Is there any build in codeigniter function?

Comment: like e.g. get_status_header() or something else?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create a file called MY_Output.php in your application/core folder with the following code:

```
<?php

if (!defined('BASEPATH'))
    exit('No direct script access allowed');

class MY_Output extends CI_Output {

    function set_status_header($code = 200, $text = '')
    {
        set_status_header($code, $text);
        $this->last_set_status_code = $code;
        return $this;
    }

    function get_status_header()
    {
        return $this->last_set_status_code;
    }

}

?>
```

You can now echo out the last status code you set like so:

```
$this->output->set_status_header('404');
echo $this->output->last_set_status_code; // outputs '404'
// or get it like so:
echo $this->output->get_status_header(); // outputs '404'
```

Comment: Thanks, but do you know about some built in function like e.g. get_status_header() or something else?

Comment: There is no such function. If you check out the CI source and/or documentation the status code ends up finally being set in Common.php via a simple header() call inside a regular function. At no point is the header code value put into an object property or value that can be retrieved, reason why I did the above and did just that.

Comment: you can create your own get_status_header() by making it in the above class MY_Output.